# Incompatible dimension when using `SparseCategoricalEntropy` loss in Keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to run the following toy model to understand how `SparseCategoricalEntropy` can be used for a classification problem. However, I am facing an error saying `ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible`.

My understanding is the output of the last layer would be a probability output of shape `[batch_size,num_classes]` where each row would sum to 1 and the true prediction that should be provided for `SparseCategoricalEntropy` is of the shape `[batch_size]`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
y = np.array([1,0,1])

print(x.shape, y.shape)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(x.shape[1],), name='X')
dense1 = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(inputs)
dense2 = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(dense1)
dense3 = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(dense2)
outputs = layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(dense3)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="test_model")

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=["accuracy", tf.keras.metrics.AUC()],
)

history = model.fit(x, y, batch_size=3, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

**[EDIT]**

As pointed out in the comments, the error is not due to the loss function. It is due to the usage of AUC metric in this context.

Comment: That error comes from AUC metric not the loss function, I tried removing it and the code worked well.

Comment: All code i found uses `AUC` with `sigmoid` and `binaryCrossentrpoy` loss  which worked fine when i updated your code that way.

Comment: @aim97 I just read the documentation on AUC metric in Keras at https://keras.io/api/metrics/classification_metrics/#auc-class and it also states that this metric is a "quality measures of binary classifiers". As you are saying, I think it doesn't work with non-binary classifiers off-hand.

Comment: All the code I saw suggests that, but I didn't really study it to say, and in the parameters you can find, `multi_label` and `num_labels` which should mean that it supports multiple classes as well, that's mainly why I commented instead of writing an answer.

Comment: I tried to change the values of those two parameters but got different errors.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem (i.e., using `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`and `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()` simultaneously led to incompatible shape error). Either of the following two workarounds solved my problem:

1. Modify labels to have one-hot encoded representation. Then, you can use `CategoricalCrossentropy` and `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()`. No need to say that your model has a softmax as its output. 
    This worked without error in TF 2.5. However, the problem is that `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()` works well for binary classification and its result is not correct when your model outputs more than one value. In fact, the model in this case, flatten all its inputs and compares them. To solve this problem, use `multi_label=True` (Note that TF/Keras documatation recommends you to set multi_label to False in case of multiclass classification. However, they assumed that you are using numeric labels.)
2. In case of binary classification, simply use `BinaryCrossentropy` as the loss function and modify the output of your model to have sigmoid activation. Then, you can safely use `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()`.